# Which implementation to get memory with it's physical address is correct?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel-module

I have need in a linux driver to get the physical memory of an allocated block of memory: this is an FPGA SOC and the memory is passed to a SGDMA FPGA module.

It comes down to a confusion over *'logical' vs 'virutual'* memory: ***are they synonymous are antonymous?***

My driver code snippet is thus:

```
unsigned long m = __get_free_pages(GFP_USER, order); // returns 'logical' address
if (m) {
    instance->read_buffer[i].order = order;
    if(1) {  // should this be 0?
        instance->read_buffer[i].virtual = (void *)m;
        instance->read_buffer[i].physical = virt_to_phys((void *)m);
    } else {  // seems like the correct option as no casts are required 
        instance->read_buffer[i].physical = m
        instance->read_buffer[i].virtual = phys_to_virt(m);
 }
```

Where the structure's defintions are:

```
struct my_structure { 
 ...
    unsigned long physical;
    void * virtual;
 ...
};
```

Both will compile without complaint (changing the `if (0)` to `if (1)`), but I don't know which is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(1)` is right.

Here are quotes about linux kernel addressing types from chapter 15 of [LDD3 book](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/):

**Kernel logical addresses**
These make up the normal address space of the kernel. These addresses map some portion (perhaps all) of main memory and are often treated as if they were physical addresses. On most architectures, logical addresses and their associated physical addresses differ only by a constant offset. ... *Memory returned from kmalloc has a kernel logical address.*

**Kernel virtual addresses**
Kernel virtual addresses are similar to logical addresses in that they are a map- ping from a kernel-space address to a physical address. Kernel virtual addresses do not necessarily have the linear, one-to-one mapping to physical addresses that characterize the logical address space, however. *All logical addresses are kernel virtual addresses, but many kernel virtual addresses are not logical addresses*.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw those quotes: but the bit that mislead me was _" ... are often treated as if they were physical addresses ... "_, which is to say that it could be interpreted as "sometimes they aren't [treated as] physical addresses".

Comment: A little digging: from chapter 8 of LDD3:  _"It’s worth stressing that memory addresses returned by kmalloc and _get_free_pages
are also virtual addresses."_  That, is *entirely* clear.

Comment: @Jamie, logical addresses could be equal to physical on some architectures, but usually that's not true. That's why you use `__virt_to_phys` to convert virtual to physical address. Search for `__virt_to_phys` inside `kernel-src/arch/` directory to see how that implemented on your architecture.